# Problems with printing on HP LaserJet Pro MFP M227sdn from Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, multi-function-printer

We recently bought a couple of HP LaserJet Pro MFP M227sdn and having problems with them. They are network connected. The first problem that we encountered is that drivers for Windows Server 2008 (x64) from HP support page didn't want to install. At the start of the installation we got an error that this OS isn't supported. I was able to extract basic driver package and install drivers with msiexec /i LM227x64 enterprise=yes (this was some advice that I found on google, but it was about other printer). ANyway, drivers was installed succesfuly and I was able to find network-connected MFP with HP Device Setup & Software. The second problem is that I wasn't able to print anything on it. It seems that jobs was transfering to print queue and instatly dissapearing. No errors in logs, no anything. It all looked like jobs was succesfuly sent to printer but it didn't print anything. After some time with google I found solution that seems a little insane for me: modify ntfs permissions on c:\windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS to add ALL group in it and aloow modify permission. And it helped instantly. So my quiestion is: Is this normal, expected solutions to install HP MFP on Windows Server 2008 R2, or there are better ways?

Answer (score 0):

I bought a HP LaserJet Pro MFP M130 and had exactly the same problem when using Windows Server 2008 (x64).  msiexec /i LM129x64.msi enterprise=yes and setting MODIFY permissions for everyone fixed also the problem for me. I guess this is a general bug HP needs to fix.